# SSIS Job failure : Script task Issue - the script returned a failure result

Tags: ssis

I do have ssis package which capture data from csv file using script task.The job ran fine without any issues but it is getting failed for past few days before . I have tried to run locally which is working fine but via SQL server Agent it is getting failed and error message also not clear. I am running job using proxy account and credentials both locally and via SQL server agent Job.
Error message : the script returned a failure result (in execution log)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error message may not be clear but you should post it anyway. Or are you saying you can't find it?

Comment: The script returned a failure result. This is the error message i am getting in execution log.

Comment: Then your script code explicitly decided to return a failure result. You need to debug it and work out why.

Comment: But when i try to run the code locally in visual studio it doesnt throw an error . any suggestion

Comment: It’s probably a user account issue. Can you see how the code would be returning DTSExecResult.Failure

Comment: Okay Thank you .let me test with  DTSExecResult.Failure . I am using Service account to run the Job and used same account to run in Visual studio as a different user , thats why confused whether it could be permission issue or not .

Comment: You might need to post the actual code here